# EMACS doesn't grey out comments

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, comment

When I comment out code with combination of `/*` and `*/` in JavaScript nothing happens with text  and it stays the same color. (You can see it in second part of code, one that is not grayed out but is commented.)

I have to use `M-;` it gets grayed out (this you can see in first part of code).

It gets grayed out if I restart Emacs after commenting it out manually.

Is there way to fix it?[image] 
EDIT: If I use `//` it grays out right away. Only problem is `/*` and `*/`.

Comment: Does it also happen if you run Emacs with `emacs -Q` (i.e., without loading your configuration)? If not, that means something you added to your configuration is responsible.